# Get the latest order ID after placed order in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want get the last order ID done after the placed order. I have used this for get the last order id.

```
        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( ' SELECT * FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` 
  ORDER BY `wp_woocommerce_order_items`.`order_item_id` DESC 
  LIMIT 1', OBJECT );
```

But apart from this, is there any other woocommerce function or hook to get the last order ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to achieve, do you want to do something with order ID after the order is placed?

Comment: that depends on where exactly you will use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just placed an order and nothing else then you can use `' $wpdb->insert_id'`.. it will do the trick.